# Travelling from the US to UK with a company computer bought in the US - do I pay VAT at UK border?

Tags: import-taxes

I live in the UK as a UK national, and the US based company that I work for has bought me a computer in the USA to use for my work with them. I'm travelling to the US from the UK for business and to visit friends soon. They will give me the computer (Mac Studio) then before I return with to the UK. It will be their property and not for my personal use. I will have to return it at the end of my time with them, which has no end date (It is open). Do I have to pay VAT? It is worth $4500 in the US.

Comment: It would make way more sense for them to just buy you a Mac Studio in the UK, given that way any import charges, regulatory compliance etc will have been taken care of by Apple or their agents.

Comment: The price difference is ridiculous, and it will also take much more time to arrive here in the UK. It's cheaper for me to go to the US and pick one up, pay the VAT when I come back. Plus, I get it sooner. I might just get it shipped. It comes to about $1000 less. And six weeks quicker.

Comment: Fair - my experience is normally once you account for VAT and shipping (+ warranty issues) it normally winds up not worth importing from the US, but those leadtime and price differences are huge!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to pay VAT. If you just bring it in your luggage as is - the backstory is absolutely irrelevant.

---

A decent company would have a shipping department that would handle this for you. They shouldn't be giving it to you to deal with, they should ship it to you and declare it accordingly and cover whatever taxes the customs require.

If you decide to carry it, they still should provide the customs documentation. Unless it was a gift to you, it's *their* computer given to you for work. You're importing a piece of business equipment. See [here](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/bringing-commercial-goods-into-great-britainin-your-baggage) for details.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote but I do not see an answer here. "Your company should have done this" does not answer "Do I need to pay tax on it?".

Comment: Is it "importing" if it's only temporarily going to be in the UK?

Comment: @Acccumulation says who? When you bring it to the UK you'll say "I'll take it back to the US, I promise", but why should anyone believe you? That's why the company should have been dealing with this.

Comment: @Willeke ok, added a direct answer, not sure how much help that is to the OP. The answer to the question is "yes, you'll need to pay VAT", but the answer to the problem is "don't do it, the company should be doing it".

Comment: @Accumulation temporary imports can be exempted from tax and duty using an ATA Carnet. Not quite sure this could be used for this scenario, though.

Comment: Better yet, they could have ordered it to be delivered directly in the UK. Also note that US and UK keyboards are different, if they ordered one. Not much but enough to be quite annoying. Make sure they order the UK version.

Comment: @littleadv I agree that exempting temporary goods is not without issues, but neither is the reverse. Surely if I take a week-long vacation to the UK, and bring a $4000 laptop with me, I don't have to pay tariffs on the laptop? If I travel from the US through Mexico to South America, do I have to pay tariffs on all my personal goods every time I enter a new country?

Comment: @Acccumulation if you come to a week long vacation, you'll probably come with a return ticket. Here you have a UK resident/citizen coming with an expensive computer which they bring *home* and telling some story that they'd take it back in some undetermined time in the future. Do you really think anyone is going to believe that?

Comment: @Acccumulation *do I have to pay tariffs on all my personal goods every time I enter a new country?* - if they *stay* to be used in that country then yes, you absolutely do.

Comment: By "stay", you mean "permanent", right? So we're back to the issue of how to determine whether something is "permanent".

Comment: @Acccumulation no, it doesn't have to be *permanent*. It has to be imported to be used in the UK, which in this case it most definitely is.

Comment: If I'm bringing my laptop on vacation, it's probably because I want to use it. And if you meant to mean "for business", what if it's a business trip?

Comment: @Acccumulation I'm not sure what's your point. You're saying that the customs may believe you that you come for a 1-week stay and will not leave your computer there? They may. Would they believe the OP? Highly unlikely. They may *not* believe you either and charge you tariffs. They're **allowed** to do that. In the case of the OP he's clearly importing the equipment. I'm not sure what your argument here is.

Comment: The issue I've found is that there isn't clear language from HMRC. But from this discussion (Thanks) I can gather that my company is essentially importing a computer for me to use, and it doesn't matter that it isn't mine. If I'm using it in the UK, I have to pay VAT. It seems computers are duty exempt from the USA (Correct me if I'm wrong). So it might be better to forget the flight, do meetings virtually and have them post it - then have them pay the VAT. It's still worth it for my work, as these computers are hard to get (Mac Studio Ultra).

Comment: @Acccumulation items in the posession of a visitor that will leave again with the visitor are generally exempt from taxation etc. But the OP isn't a visitor, but a resident. There are processes to exempt items from import taxes for temporary imports, but they ar enormally contingent on the temporary import being for certain purposes - eg repair or similar.